# Making sure only a single if-else statement is allowed to execute

Tags: java

I'm a bit lost as to what kind of statement I could use to solve my problem.

I am writing a program that will take four randomNumbers and four playerGuesses. If the first, second, third or fourth randomNumber matches with the first, second, third or fourth playerGuess respectively, they are awarded a Red pin for each match (So a maximum of 4, a minimum of 0). If the playerGuess number does appear in the randomNumber sequence, but is in the wrong place, the player is rewarded with a White pin. If a red pin is awarded for a randomNumber (meaning a correct guess on the correct place), no white pin can be rewarded for that number anymore.

**Example:**

randomNumber sequence (0, 1, 2, 3) matched with playerGuesses (0, 2, 2, 1) will result in 2 red pins and 1 white pin).

The code below shows the process for determining the red and white pins. Please note that both randomNumber and playerGuesses are arrays of four integers.

```
//Determining the amount of red and white pins
if (randomNumbers[0] == playerGuesses[0])
    {Red = Red+1;}
        else if (randomNumbers[0] == playerGuesses[1] || randomNumbers[0] == playerGuesses[2] || randomNumbers[0] == playerGuesses[3]) 
            {White = White+1;}
if (randomNumbers[1] == playerGuesses[1])
    {Red = Red+1;}
        else if (randomNumbers[1] == playerGuesses[0] || randomNumbers[1] == playerGuesses[2] || randomNumbers[1] == playerGuesses[3]) 
            {White = White+1;}
if (randomNumbers[2] == playerGuesses[2])
    {Red = Red+1;}
        else if (randomNumbers[2] == playerGuesses[0] || randomNumbers[2] == playerGuesses[1] || randomNumbers[2] == playerGuesses[3]) 
            {White = White+1;}
if (randomNumbers[3]==playerGuesses[3])
    {Red = Red+1;}
        else if (randomNumbers[3] == playerGuesses[0] || randomNumbers[3] == playerGuesses[1] || randomNumbers[3] == playerGuesses[2]) 
            {White = White+1;}
```

One very specific problem occurs when multiple if-else statements turn up true. It is best shown with an example:

Computer generates: (4 9 7 7)

Player guesses: (1 7 1 1)

The console returns: 2 white pins, 0 red pins.

In this example, none of the if-statements that determine red pins are triggered. So, all if-else statements are run for determining white pins.

The problem is that the "7" in the player's guesses triggers both the third and fourth if-else statement for adding white pins, resulting in two white pins. The game is meant to award only one white pin for this, however.

Do you guys have any idea how to make sure any playerGuess is only able to trigger one white pin, when no red pins are awarded.

(I hope all information needed to answer my question is provided!)

Comment: Use `else if` statement ?

Comment: I already did, but the problem is that it is triggering more than one if-else statement!

Comment: I meant use else if for all statements. What you have now is two conditions at a time. it should be (depending on your logic of course) `if ( condition1 ){ ...} else if (condition2){ ....} else if (condition3){...}...else if (condition n){...} else{....}`

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you correctly:
For the given example `(4 9 7 7)`  vs`(1 7 1 1)` your desired result is `(1 white pins, 0 red pins)`
instead of the actual result `(2 white pins, 0 red pins)`. Correct?

Comment: Yes Thomas Fritsch, that is exactly what I mean!

Answer (score 0):

```
        if (randomNumbers [0] == playerGuesses [0])
{Red = Red+1;}
    else if (randomNumbers[0] == playerGuesses[1] || randomNumbers[0] == playerGuesses[2] || randomNumbers[0] == playerGuesses[3]) 
        {White = White+1;}
if (randomNumbers[1] == playerGuesses[1])
    {Red = Red+1;}
        else if (randomNumbers[1] == playerGuesses[2] || randomNumbers[1] == playerGuesses[3]) 
            {White = White+1;}
if (randomNumbers[2] == playerGuesses[2])
    {Red = Red+1;}
        else if ( randomNumbers[2] == playerGuesses[3]) 
            {White = White+1;}
if (randomNumbers[3]==playerGuesses[3])
    {Red = Red+1;}
```

This should fix your code. You rechecked some conditions up to 3 times, like if randomNumbers[0] == playerGuesses[1].
This has the effect inflating the number of times a condition is actually met, as you checked
for it more than one time. 
Using your example and your original code,

Computer generates: (4 9 7 7)

Player guesses: (1 7 1 1)

Your code checks if randomNumbers[2] == playerGuesses[3] in your 3rd else if statement, and then
if randomNumbers[3] == playerGuesses[2] in your fourth else if statement . As you can see,
this checks the same condition twice, and so will give 2 white pins instead of 1 white pin. 
The re-made code will ensure that this doesn't happen.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a different approach,
with a simpler logic and fewer `if` statements.
It also solves your problem of too many white pins.

1. Determine the number of red pins.
2. Determine the total number of pins (red + white):
   For every possible number (0, 1, 2, 3, ... 9) count how many times it
   occurs in both arrays.
   The smaller of these two counts contributes to
   the total number of pins.
3. Calculate the number of white pins (total - red).

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] randomNumbers = {4, 9, 7, 7};
    int[] playerGuesses = {1, 7, 1, 1};
    compare(randomNumbers, playerGuesses);
}

/**
 * Determine the amount of red and white pins
 */
private static void compare(int[] randomNumbers, int[] playerGuesses) {
    int red = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++) {
        if (randomNumbers[i] == playerGuesses[i]) {
            red++;
        }
    }
    int total = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
        total += Math.min(frequency(randomNumbers, x), frequency(playerGuesses, x));
    }   
    int white = total - red;
    System.out.println(white + " white pins, " + red + " red pins");
}

/**
 * Determine how many times the value x occurs in the array
 */
private static int frequency(int[] array, int x) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i] == x) {
            result++;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```